# How do I check the latency of OAuth token API of AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am refering to this endpoint.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

I could not see any cloudwatch metrics related to it. How do I check the latency of OAuthtoken API of AWS Cognito ?

Comment: Why would you expect a metric to exist for that, you do not control that endpoint and have no influence over the latency of it anyway!?

Comment: We have exposed an oauth endpoint to our partners. They want to have a latency estimate for that endpoint.

Comment: Then call the endpoint once and measure the response time.

Comment: But, that will be a single datapoint. We need p99, p99.5 and avg latency. If the metrics had been generated out of box, i would have used those. Like API gateway generates.

Comment: It makes little sense to expose those metrics, you will have metrics and cannot do anything based on them. If the client wants the metric they can measure them themselves. You do not get S3 latency metrics, no SQS latency metrics, etc. Why are you / is the client interested in them?